# Rails render :new changes to different url when form data is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following code in my user controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = 'employee'
    if @user.save
      redirect_to jobs_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

and I have following routes.

`resources :users, only: [:new, :create]`

Now when i visit `http://localhost:3000/users/new` and submit form with correct data then everything works fine. But if form validation fails then above url changes to `http://localhost:3000/users`. Since I don't have `/users` in my route, I will get 404 if I press enter with above url. Is there any way to keep url to `http://localhost:3000/users/new` when form is invalid rather than changing it to `http://localhost:3000/users` ? Changing `render :new` to `redirect_to new_user_path` will solve the problem but then I will lose all the errors of form object and can't display any error message to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your problem, you can redirect to new_user_path with put params like sample below
if rails fail to save @user, then it will save errors in @user.errors
and you can check the content like messages below to show user

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = 'employee'
    if @user.save
      redirect_to jobs_path
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path(messages: @user.errors.messages)
    end
  end
```

in your new form you can check whether with params[:messages]

for better manage showing errors messages you can check [this link](http://stevenleiva.com/flash-messages-in-rails)

Comment: I changed my code to @user.errors.messages, it will directly show you all the errors